# Determining if the mouse is on top of a box

Tags: c#

I have 4 picture boxes and a collision detection to see if my mouse is on top of any of them, but I have to run the same code 4 different times, but just changing the name. Also, the `else if` statements can be regular `if` statements.

```
PictureBox display = sender as PictureBox;
Point drop = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

if (((displayCollision(drop, pbDisplay1)) == true) && (display != pbDisplay1))
{
    display.Location = pbDisplay1.Location;
    display.Size = pbDisplay1.Size;

    pbDisplay1.Location = defaultLocation;
    pbDisplay1.Size = defaultSize;
}
else if (((displayCollision(drop, pbDisplay2)) == true) && (display != pbDisplay2))
{
    display.Location = pbDisplay2.Location;
    display.Size = pbDisplay2.Size;

    pbDisplay2.Location = defaultLocation;
    pbDisplay2.Size = defaultSize;
}
else if (((displayCollision(drop, pbDisplay3)) == true) && (display != pbDisplay3))
{
    display.Location = pbDisplay3.Location;
    display.Size = pbDisplay3.Size;

    pbDisplay3.Location = defaultLocation;
    pbDisplay3.Size = defaultSize;
}
else if (((displayCollision(drop, pbDisplay4)) == true) && (display != pbDisplay4))
{ 
    display.Location = pbDisplay4.Location;
    display.Size = pbDisplay4.Size;

    pbDisplay4.Location = defaultLocation;
    pbDisplay4.Size = defaultSize;
}
else 
{
    display.Location = defaultLocation;
}
```

Comment: Start creating a method for the body of the various _if_ passing the variables involved

Comment: i thought that too, if it cant be done in a loop ill just do that

Comment: When you start naming variables with numbers appended to the end, it is generally a sign you should be using an array/collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a convenient way to do a `for` loop, but you could extract common functionality into a single function:

```
bool CheckAndModify(PictureBox pb)
{
    if (displayCollision(drop, pb) && (display != pb))
    {
        display.Location = pb.Location;
        display.Size = pb.Size;
        pb.Location = defaultLocation;
        pb.Size = defaultSize;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then:

```
bool modified = CheckAndModify(pbDisplay1) ||
                CheckAndModify(pbDisplay2) ||
                CheckAndModify(pbDisplay3) ||
                CheckAndMovify(pbDisplay4);
```

Or, I suppose a loop would be possible:

```
foreach (var pbDisplay in new[]{pbDisplay1, pbDisplay2, pbDisplay3, pbDisplay4})
{
    if (CheckAndModify(pbDisplay))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```